# Unable to initiate spyder on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, spyder

I installed spyder using `pip install spyder`.

The installation process starts with:

```
$ pip install spyder
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting spyder
  Downloading spyder-5.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (14.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14.9/14.9 MB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting cookiecutter>=1.6.0
  Downloading cookiecutter-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyxdg>=0.26 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder) (0.27)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=2.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder) (4.0.0)
Collecting atomicwrites>=1.2.0
  Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.1.tar.gz (14 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
```

and ends with:

```
Using cached mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: atomicwrites, intervaltree
  Building wheel for atomicwrites (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for atomicwrites: filename=atomicwrites-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=6957 sha256=702910f329f7bd912e36e76d1c042c0bbe2cc599d6a22f285fe8257f506e1170
  Stored in directory: /home/pkj/.cache/pip/wheels/34/07/0b/33b15f68736109f72ea0bb2499521d87312b932620737447a2
  Building wheel for intervaltree (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for intervaltree: filename=intervaltree-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=26119 sha256=8d663bc126daf8aedca47d28f58398e018d8933b92c42550fe8233faf24c95ec
  Stored in directory: /home/pkj/.cache/pip/wheels/fa/80/8c/43488a924a046b733b64de3fac99252674c892a4c3801c0a61
Successfully built atomicwrites intervaltree
Installing collected packages: webencodings, wcwidth, text-unidecode, sortedcontainers, snowballstemmer, PyQtWebEngine-Qt5, PyQt5-Qt5, pure-eval, pickleshare, fastjsonschema, wurlitzer, whatthepatch, watchdog, ujson, typing-extensions, types-python-dateutil, traitlets, tornado, tomlkit, tomli, tinycss2, textdistance, tabulate, sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml, sphinxcontrib-qthelp, sphinxcontrib-jsmath, sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp, sphinxcontrib-devhelp, sphinxcontrib-applehelp, soupsieve, rtree, rpds-py, pyzmq, python-slugify, PyQt5-sip, pylint-venv, pygments, pyflakes, pydocstyle, pycodestyle, psutil, prompt-toolkit, pluggy, platformdirs, pathspec, parso, pandocfilters, packaging, nest-asyncio, mypy-extensions, mistune, mdurl, mccabe, jupyterlab-pygments, Jinja2, jellyfish, isort, intervaltree, inflection, importlib-metadata, imagesize, executing, exceptiongroup, docutils, docstring-to-markdown, dill, diff-match-patch, defusedxml, decorator, debugpy, cloudpickle, bleach, binaryornot, babel, attrs, atomicwrites, asttokens, alabaster, yapf, three-merge, stack-data, sphinx, referencing, qtpy, qstylizer, pytoolconfig, python-lsp-jsonrpc, pyqt5, matplotlib-inline, markdown-it-py, jupyter-core, jedi, flake8, comm, black, beautifulsoup4, autopep8, astroid, arrow, rich, qtawesome, qdarkstyle, python-lsp-server, pyqtwebengine, pylint, numpydoc, jupyter-client, jsonschema-specifications, ipython, rope, python-lsp-black, pyls-spyder, jsonschema, ipykernel, cookiecutter, spyder-kernels, qtconsole, nbformat, nbclient, nbconvert, spyder
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.1.3 PyQt5-Qt5-5.15.2 PyQt5-sip-12.13.0 PyQtWebEngine-Qt5-5.15.2 alabaster-0.7.16 arrow-1.3.0 astroid-3.0.3 asttokens-2.4.1 atomicwrites-1.4.1 attrs-23.2.0 autopep8-2.0.4 babel-2.14.0 beautifulsoup4-4.12.3 binaryornot-0.4.4 black-24.2.0 bleach-6.1.0 cloudpickle-3.0.0 comm-0.2.1 cookiecutter-2.5.0 debugpy-1.8.1 decorator-5.1.1 defusedxml-0.7.1 diff-match-patch-20230430 dill-0.3.8 docstring-to-markdown-0.13 docutils-0.20.1 exceptiongroup-1.2.0 executing-2.0.1 fastjsonschema-2.19.1 flake8-7.0.0 imagesize-1.4.1 importlib-metadata-7.0.1 inflection-0.5.1 intervaltree-3.1.0 ipykernel-6.29.2 ipython-8.21.0 isort-5.13.2 jedi-0.19.1 jellyfish-1.0.3 jsonschema-4.21.1 jsonschema-specifications-2023.12.1 jupyter-client-8.6.0 jupyter-core-5.7.1 jupyterlab-pygments-0.3.0 markdown-it-py-3.0.0 matplotlib-inline-0.1.6 mccabe-0.7.0 mdurl-0.1.2 mistune-3.0.2 mypy-extensions-1.0.0 nbclient-0.9.0 nbconvert-7.16.0 nbformat-5.9.2 nest-asyncio-1.6.0 numpydoc-1.6.0 packaging-23.2 pandocfilters-1.5.1 parso-0.8.3 pathspec-0.12.1 pickleshare-0.7.5 platformdirs-4.2.0 pluggy-1.4.0 prompt-toolkit-3.0.43 psutil-5.9.8 pure-eval-0.2.2 pycodestyle-2.11.1 pydocstyle-6.3.0 pyflakes-3.2.0 pygments-2.17.2 pylint-3.0.3 pylint-venv-3.0.3 pyls-spyder-0.4.0 pyqt5-5.15.10 pyqtwebengine-5.15.6 python-lsp-black-2.0.0 python-lsp-jsonrpc-1.1.2 python-lsp-server-1.10.0 python-slugify-8.0.4 pytoolconfig-1.3.1 pyzmq-25.1.2 qdarkstyle-3.2.3 qstylizer-0.2.2 qtawesome-1.3.0 qtconsole-5.5.1 qtpy-2.4.1 referencing-0.33.0 rich-13.7.0 rope-1.12.0 rpds-py-0.18.0 rtree-1.2.0 snowballstemmer-2.2.0 sortedcontainers-2.4.0 soupsieve-2.5 sphinx-7.2.6 sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.8 sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.6 sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-2.0.5 sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1 sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.7 sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.10 spyder-5.5.1 spyder-kernels-2.5.0 stack-data-0.6.3 tabulate-0.9.0 text-unidecode-1.3 textdistance-4.6.1 three-merge-0.1.1 tinycss2-1.2.1 tomli-2.0.1 tomlkit-0.12.3 tornado-6.4 traitlets-5.14.1 types-python-dateutil-2.8.19.20240106 typing-extensions-4.9.0 ujson-5.9.0 watchdog-4.0.0 wcwidth-0.2.13 webencodings-0.5.1 whatthepatch-1.0.5 wurlitzer-3.0.3 yapf-0.40.2
```

while I try to  `$ spyder` from terminal, I receive the following error:

> bash: /home/pkj/.local/Spyder-5.5.1/envs/spyder-5.5.1/bin/spyder: No such file or directory

Can comeone suggest me a fix for this?

Comment: That looks like a bug, have you checked the bugtrackers or filed one yourself?